# Callback before Force Close of Android Activity?

Tags: android

I'd like to have some emergency cleanup code execute just before my app crashes. I tried using onDestroy(),, onFinal() and finalize() to no avail. Is this possible in an Android Activity?

Comment: Force close = Activity Badly written.

Comment: @Jorgesys, either every single app I've ever used is "badly written" or there are unforeseen circumstances that cause all apps to crash (preferably not very often).

Comment: Badly Written, read this...
http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html
I have recently released a new version of my app and all of the force close messages displayed after the latest version now are gone, the implementation of Asynchtask will do the job even with a slow connection 
http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 2):

Well, I would recommend not having your app crash in the first place. If there's something that COULD crash, just put a try/catch around it and handle it properly.

Or, as some sort of global try/catch, you can use `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()`. Finally, you could even consider `Runtime.addShutdownHook`, but that's most likely a bad idea.

Comment: I'll give this a try. I'm using a hardware accelerator so when Android  loads my new program it doesn't call stop or anything and that causes my other process to be in the wrong state.

Answer (score 0):

just implement Error handling, and call your cleanup code.

```
try {
...
...
...
} catch (Exception e) { 
cleanupcode();//cleanup code execute just before my app crashes
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

you will not see the Force Close Dialog but if you want to force to close just call

```
   super.finish();
```