# How to clear a notification if activity crashes?

Tags: android, crash, android-activity, notifications

In my app, I'm creating a notification with the FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT flag set as such..

```
Notification notification = new Notification(iconId, text, System.currentTimeMillis());  
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

I'm cancelling the notification in onDestroy, but if my app crashes before calling onDestroy, is there any way to have my notification go away?

Rob W.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Callback before Force Close of Android Activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313960/callback-before-force-close-of-android-activity)

Comment: @EboMike if you know of a way to write 100% robust code that never crashes (without effectively wrapping ur code all in a try-catch) for a rather complicated normal-usasge android app, then... plz - divulge how you can accomplish such methods of coding

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Everything crashes, even Google applications. I use `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()` and the following handler code:

```
package my.package;

import java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;

public class CrashHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler
{
  private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345;

  private UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;
  private NotificationManager notificationManager;

  public CrashHandler(Context context)
  {
    this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  }

  public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)
  {
    if (notificationManager != null)
    {
      try
      {
        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
      }
      catch (Throwable ex)
      {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    notificationManager = null;

    defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain simply how you use this class ?

Answer (score 5):

This is more or less the same question as [Callback before Force Close of Android Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313960/callback-before-force-close-of-android-activity), so I'll repeat my answer here:

I would recommend not having your app crash in the first place. If there's something that COULD crash, just put a try/catch around it and handle it properly.

Or, as some sort of global try/catch, you can use `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()`. Finally, you could even consider Runtime.addShutdownHook, but that's most likely a bad idea.

Fix your crashes. That's the only sane solution.

Comment: Yah that particular crash has been fixed, I was just hoping there was some way to handle it better in the field for any future bugs that may crop up and cause my app to crash.

Answer (score 2):

No. When your app crashes, there's nothing that can be done after the crash! Either catch the exception and deal with it then (although `catch Exception e {...}` is an *extremely* bad idea), or make your app not crash (this would be a good tactic in my opinion).