# How to cancel alarms when application crashes , which method will call when app crash?

Tags: android, android-alarms

In my application I have alarm manager in that i am passing pendingintent. suppose if application crash at that time this alarm are not canceling. how to cancel alarm when application crash. where i need to write code to cancel the alarms if application crashes.

Comment: Have you found why your app crashed? try to fix it

Comment: Other Than this any Solution is there

Comment: try{/*crash occurs*/}catch(exception e){/*cancel alarm*/}

Comment: If we don't know where it crash in future at that time how to solve this one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cancelling an alarm after program crash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818333/cancelling-an-alarm-after-program-crash)