# How to delete temp files on app crashes

Tags: android

My aplication sometims has lots of temporary files.But it is not finished so time to time I have app crashes. I wish to know how i can delete them in such situation.
At this moment I am deleting them when app starting, which does not seem to be a good practice.

Comment: maybe use try catch blocks and when app crashes delete temp files.

Comment: u mean u want to clear application data?

Comment: You can try to use global exception handler as described here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427515/using-global-exception-handling-on-android

Comment: This is roughly the same question as this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313960/callback-before-force-close-of-android-activity

Comment: you can delete temperory files and folders in the same activity's onDestroy method where you are creating it, only problem is-- if you are calling other activity2 from that activity and if you are using that files in that activity2.  To avoid this simply delete that files or folder in first activity's onResume method and recreates folder. you will get help for deleting temporary files/folders anywhere.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1219199/beworker I think your link is better, post it as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After each successfull update of cache, I save status to preferences. On Application start if status represent potentional corruction of data I clean it. Thats much more reliable then tryin to clean on crash.